# Determine if the selected email is from inbox or sent items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am programming an **Outlook Add-in** and need to determine whether a selected email is from `Inbox` or `Sent Items` so that I can tag the email with folder="Inbox" or "Sent" when I save it in my database.

I understand that I can compare the folder name to Inbox or Sent Items and determine the folder, however, how do I determine when the email selected is sitting in one of the sub-folders in the inbox. Is there a `FolderType` property to check whether the selected email's folder is **inbox** or **sent** (*similar to identifying an item type with `OlItemType`*)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look at the [`MailItem.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863655.aspx) and cast it to a [`Outlook.Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863890.aspx). Once you have the `Folder`, you can access the display name via [`Folder.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869734.aspx). If you want to determine whether the selected item is a subfolder of `Inbox`, you would need to recursively call up the `Parent` tree until `Parent` is null to find the root parent folder.

```
Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = explorer.Selection.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>().First();
Outlook.Folder parentFolder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder;
if (parentFolder.Parent == null) // we are at the root
{
  string folderName = parentFolder.Name;
}
else
  // .. recurse up the parent tree casting parentFolder.Parent as Outlook.Folder...
```

You should obviously add *error handling* and *object disposal* to this sample code.