# How to retrieve the Outlook folder of a mail item (Outlook.MailItem)?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-2010

I am getting my default inbox folder via `inboxFolder = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox`

Elsewhere in my code, I begin doing a foreach loop to extract specific information I want from these MailItems

```
foreach (var item in this.inboxFolder.Items)
{
   Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
   //.... doing stuff here
   string SenderEmail = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
   string SenderName = mailItem.SenderName;
   string FolderLocation = mailItem.???;  //how to retrieve folder location?
   //.... more stuff here
}
```

For example: A user may have created a subfolder called 'Test' shown below.

[image: An image of a user-created subfolder in Outlook-2010]

Comment: You need to check the `Parent` property. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11942074/44522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean folder path? Use MAPIFolder.FullFolderPath. Or MAPIFoldert.Name if you only need the name.

Also keep in mind that the value will be the same for all items in the folder, so there is no reason to evaluate it on each step of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'm evaluating it as we speak but I did want to mention that if my default Inbox folder has a subfolder in it, a foreach loop on the main folder path has subfolder items.  It looks like I may have to evaluate the MAPIFolder.Name for each item if that's the case.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for the pointer guys. However I was having some trouble implementing the same initially. Here is how I solved it, just in case if some one faces the same issue.

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder parentFolder = mailItemToDelete.Parent as Outlook.MAPIFolder;
string FolderLocation = parentFolder.FolderPath;
```

The Parent object is dynamic and hence was causing issue.