# How to check if a mailItem is in the default Outlook Deleted items folder

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In Outlook 2007 I have a reference to a mailItem object. And I want to know if the mailItem is in the delete items folder.

I am aware that I can use the mailitem's parent property to find out the folder that the mailItem is in. For example [this question shows how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011029/how-to-retrieve-the-outlook-folder-of-a-mail-item-outlook-mailitem)

The issue I have is that the Name property of the folder changes depending on the language of the Exchange Server or on something other than Outlook's language settings..

I was hoping to find a property on the folder object that would return Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems but I cannot find it.

Thus is there a language neutral method to determine whether a folder object is the deleted items folder?

***Edit and possible only answer***
I suppose I could get the DeletedItems folder with the Namespace method "GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems)" and then compare the Name property of this folder object with the name property of the folder of the mailItem.

***Edit***
See below for a similar idea but using the entryID as the property to compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)`, retrieve the parent folder (`MailItem.Parent`), then compare their entry ids (`MAPIFolder.EntryID`) using `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`.

Namespace can be retrieved from `Application.Session` or `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")`